# Retrieve "Artist" field for a track with SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

is it possible to access track metadata (more specifically, the "Artist" and "Composer" fields) with the API?

The "tracks" endpoint does not seem to retrieve this information.

I used this simple [example](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#basic) found in the documentation for the JavaScript SDK:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'my_client_id'});

SC.get('/tracks/12345').then(function(tracks){
    alert('Latest track: ' + tracks[0].title);
});
```

So I receive a lot of track information but none of the metadata fields (artist, publisher, composer, etc...)

Has anyone managed to extract that info with the API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no way of getting that information with an acccuracy of 100%. Have a look at the API refernce at https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks, there are listed all the possible parameters you can query to the api.

There are no "Artist"- or "Composer"-Values, as SoundCloud doesn't compare the uploaded tracks with official release information. The only thing you can display as "Artist" is the username of the user who uploaded the audio, who, of course, isn't the actual artist in nearly every case.

Although some songs have the artist in the title (like "Sia - Chandelier"), you can't rely on that.

Comment: Thanks. I had already seen the API. I was wondering if there is any other way of retrieving the metadata fields because SoundCloud does offer these fields for each track and does store them in their DB. But apparently, the API does not give access to this data.

Comment: actually i also need to pull artist name from track but it seems it could not possible , cuz they are not providing.:(

Comment: @RamkeshYadav, as a workaround (not a solution) I ended up inserting the artist name in the track's tag list as a Machine Tag. (see the tag_list geo:lon example in http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks). Hope it helps.